# Discord.py private channel event

Tags: python, api, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to do a support bot for my Discord Server. I have the [Tickets](https://ticketsbot.net/) bot installed so people on the server can create a support ticket. Every time they open a ticket a new private channel is created.

What I want to do is to have my bot send an automatic message to this newly created private channel. I think I'm supposed to use `discord.on_private_channel_create(channel)` but I am pretty sure I'm using it wrong.

This is what I have

```
import discord

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async  def on_ready():
    print("bot is now online")
@client.event
async def on_private_channel_create(channel):
    await channel.send("A new channel has been created!")

client.run("KEY")
```

Thank you in advance c:

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved, I was using the wrong function. You're supposed to use `on_guild_channel_create(channel)`

```
import discord

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async  def on_ready():
    print("Bot is now online")

@client.event
async def on_guild_channel_create(channel):
    """
    This event is called whenever a guild (server) channel is created.
    This can be a voice channel, a text channel, or a category channel.
    The guild can be accessed by ``channel.guild``
    Args:
        channel:
            A TextChannel or VoiceChannel or CategoryChannel object that is created.
    """
    print(channel, "is created in", channel.guild)
    await channel.send("Hello There")


client.run("KEY")
```